# How to integrate Angular.js with a realtime messaging service like Pusher or PubNub?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pusher, pubnub

Is it possible to define Pusher or PubNub as an Angular Service?
Does someone have code examples of such an integration?

Answer (score 8):

Someone already made it :-): http://jsfiddle.net/bv5Kq/13/

Be sure to check out the wiki for examples: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/JsFiddle-Examples

Comment: In my opinion, using an Angular service that would wrap the PUBNUB code would make more sense than placing the PUBNUB code in a controller. Of course, that could be just example code. Something to keep in mind. More information: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services

Answer (score 1):

There is AngularFire, for working with Firebase - http://angularfire.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. It has color changing, emoticons, clickable hyperlinks and multiple channels. No database or sockets required, just a PubNub account: http://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/advanced-angular-chatroom-tutorial-no-database-or-sockets-required/

Answer (score 0):

There is a somewhat "unofficial" AngularJS library for PubNub. It is a simple service wrapper for the global PUBNUB library object. The main code is in app/scripts/pubnub-angular.coffee and looks like this:

```
angular.module('pubnub.angular.service', [])
  .factory 'PubNub', () -> PUBNUB
```

You can find the GitHub repository here:

https://github.com/pubnub/angular-js

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://disparity.github.io/angular-pusher/, module for integration pusher events into angular event system