# How to render or populate data coming from websocket services like pusher using angularjs ngRepeat?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-5.1, pusher

I am new to realtime application and its bothering for a while how to render the data coming from websocket services like pusher using the angularjs ngRepeat directive..
below are the response from the api
and the snippets code i have.

**Client Side.**

```
$scope.exam_results = [{}];
    var client = new Pusher('some_key');
    var pusher = $pusher(client);
    var my_channel = pusher.subscribe('some_channel');
    my_channel.bind('some_event', function(data) {
        $scope.some_var = data;
        console.log($scope.some_var);
    });
```

**Server Side**

```
.....
LaravelPusher::trigger($some_channel, 'some_event',  $some_var);
```

By the way im using laravel and angularjs.

Need little help here guys.. thank you ^_^

**Api Response**

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "subject_id": 1,
    "student_id": 1,
    "correct": 0,
    "incorrect": 30,
    "created_at": "2016-02-17 17:47:36",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "exam_taken": 1,
    "students": {
      "id": 1,
      "firstname": "Mary Rose",
      "lastname": "Labrador",
      "middlename": "Neneng",
      "birthdate": "2016-02-10",
      "email": "maryrose@dummy.com",
      "username": "maryrose",
      "gender": "Female",
      "password": "65ce8ebfe1687cb8a5460fab48bcea413a0e17f53636912ac4667f056eeca461",
      "guardianname": "Unnamed",
      "guardiancontact": "+6309083561578",
      "personalcontact": "+6309083561578",
      "department_id": 1,
      "taken_exam": 1,
      "created_at": "2016-02-16 00:00:00",
      "updated_at": "2016-02-17 17:47:58"
    },
    "subjects": {
      "id": 1,
      "subjectname": "Algorithm",
      "slug": "algorithm",
      "time": "10:00:00",
      "schedule": "MWF",
      "teacher_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2016-02-12 09:28:27",
      "updated_at": "2016-02-12 09:28:27"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "subject_id": 1,
    "student_id": 4,
    "correct": 0,
    "incorrect": 30,
    "created_at": "2016-02-17 18:54:11",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "exam_taken": 1,
    "students": {
      "id": 4,
      "firstname": "Joan Phylis",
      "lastname": "Rogano",
      "middlename": "Latoja",
      "birthdate": "2016-02-14",
      "email": "joangwapa@dummy.com",
      "username": "joan143",
      "gender": "Female",
      "password": "65ce8ebfe1687cb8a5460fab48bcea413a0e17f53636912ac4667f056eeca461",
      "guardianname": "Unnamed",
      "guardiancontact": "+639083561578",
      "personalcontact": "+639083561578",
      "department_id": 1,
      "taken_exam": 1,
      "created_at": "2016-02-16 00:00:00",
      "updated_at": "2016-02-17 18:57:43"
    },
    "subjects": {
      "id": 1,
      "subjectname": "Algorithm",
      "slug": "algorithm",
      "time": "10:00:00",
      "schedule": "MWF",
      "teacher_id": 1,
      "created_at": "2016-02-12 09:28:27",
      "updated_at": "2016-02-12 09:28:27"
    }
  }
]
```

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-reapeat="result in exam_results track by $index">
                    <td>
                        <span class="text-success">@{{result.students.lastname}}, 
                            @{{result.students.firstname}} @{{result.students.middlename}}
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="fa fa-eye pull-right"> View</a></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: If `$scope.some_var`,is an array, why not just use `Array.concat()` to add the new `data` to it? Angular's digest cycle would then render it.

Comment: please show some snnipet

Comment: $scope.some_var.concat(data). is that it?

Comment: Made it into an answer so the snippet is readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$scope.exam_results` is an array, why not just use `Array.concat()` to add the new `data` to it? Angular's digest cycle would then render it:

```
$scope.exam_results = [];

// your websocket code

my_channel.bind('some_event', function(data) {
    $scope.exam_results.concat(data);
    console.log($scope.exam_results);
});
```

Obviously, the data from the websocket needs to be the same format over time and also an array of objects. You would bind your `ng-repeat` to `$scope.exam_results`.

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="result in exam_results track by $index">
       {{result.students.firstname}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, it's  an array. I don't know what you are trying to render, though. Since it is just a PNG, it's not really easy to say if all data sets are the same.

Comment: `code` [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "subject_id": 1,
    "student_id": 1,
    "correct": 0,
    "incorrect": 30,
    "created_at": "2016-02-17 17:47:36",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
    "exam_taken": 1,
    "students": {
      "id": 1,
      "firstname": "Mary Rose",
      "lastname": "Labrador",
      "middlename": "Neneng",
      "birthdate": "2016-02-10",
    },

Comment: its an empty array with your snippet, when i try to initialize the $scope.some_var into an empty array, but in array of object the log result to [Object]

Comment: [Object] as an array of objects is exactly what is in your PNG. See my updated answer how to render this.

Comment: Also: please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528403/how-to-integrate-angular-js-with-a-realtime-messaging-service-like-pusher-or-pub?rq=1

Comment: is it neccesarry to nest the ngRepeat directive,? i normal ajax in angularjs you only have  to access the nested property which is the students in this case? by the way i got empty result

Comment: this the server side code by the way.    $results = Semisterexaminationresult::with('students', 'subjects')
                        ->where('subject_id', $subject->id)
                        ->get();

Comment: The outer data structure is an array, so yes, you need nested repeats unless you know 100% this array has only one entry - judging by your PNG that's not the case. Please explain the data you expect from the websockets, is it a stream of outer data or students? Please copy more of that JSON and append it to your question.

Comment: OK, so students was not an array, that slipped my eye. So you can get rid of the double repeat, see my update.

Comment: Then set up a JSbin or something. I don't think you actually tried that code.

Answer (score 0):

If your event data is consistently going to be an Array of Objects.

You can do something like this -

```
$scope.exam_results = []; // Changed this to Array.
var client = new Pusher('some_key');
var pusher = $pusher(client);
var my_channel = pusher.subscribe('some_channel');
my_channel.bind('some_event', function(data) {
    $scope.exam_results.concat(data) // Concatinating Array to merge with existing Results.
});
```

Now you can have your view something like this -

```
<div ng-repeat="result in exam_results">
 <!-- HTML to render Result -->
 <span>{{result.students.first_name}}</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what if it is an array of objects?

Comment: Edited the Answer to accommodate for both. Now it doesn't matter if its a single object or an Array of objects.

Comment: when i initialize the the $scope.exa_results to an empty array([]) i got empty array on the console, and if initialize it with [{}] i got [Object] in console, and the response from api is two objects

Comment: Yeah. So what you essentially need to do is; when Pusher send you the event data, you need to Add those objects in the `$scope.exam_results`. And what you are seeing in console means - Array contains object, but that object has nothing.

Comment: but when i try in this way $scope.exam_result = data i got this [Object Object]

Comment: the problem is how will i resolve this in the view with ngRepeat?

Comment: can you edit the question and show some code of your HTML as well? It will be easier to understand the problem.

Comment: What you have in your HTML seems to be correct. What's the issue you are facing now?

Comment: its a typo in my directive